# GCS: how to upload to bucket as Storage Object Admin

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

If I grant privileges as Storage Object Admin to someone in order for them to upload data in a bucket, how can they do so?

I have created two GCS accounts and did the experiment of creating a project in account A and granting Storage Object Admin to account B. Nonetheless, when I check the list of avaliable buckets at B nothing shows up.

I am new to GCS. I know the question may seem basic but I did not find anything in the documentation that helps me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I check the list of avaliable buckets"? How do you check this?

Answer (score -1):

As specified in [Cloud IAM Roles for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) documentation, the `roles/storage.admin` role `Grants full control of buckets and objects.` for the user account. Which means that this account can list, upload and delete objects in the bucket and modify the bucket's settings.

I assume that you open the `Cloud Shell` in Project B and you are trying to run the command `gsutil ls` as [specified in Cloud Storage > Documentation > Listing Buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets) documentation. However this command will list the buckets only from the Project B, that is why you can't see the buckets of Project A there. To do so, set up the project to be Project A in the `Cloud Shell`. You can do this by running the command `gcloud config set project [PROJECT_A_ID]`, as specified in [gcloud config set](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/config/set#project) documentation. Then list the buckets again and you will see the buckets from Project A listed there.

Also to upload to the bucket you can refer to the [Uploading Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) documentation. Run this command from Project B's `Cloud Shell` and replace the `[DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]` with the Project A's bucket name. Since the role is granted properly you will be able to upload the file successfully.

I have tested this myself and it worked for me as expected.

Comment: I think you are mistaking `roles/storage.objectAdmin` and `roles/storage.admin`. OP is asking about the former. Your answer is about the latter.